# BroadcastReceiver with Handler

Tags: android

I am trying to detect the route of the buses with the aid of the WIFI access point (AP) based on Crowd sourcing . Not all buses are equipped with these WIFI AP. The detection works fine with the `BroadcastReceiver` but I want to handle the case when the user is sitting in a bus without WIFI AP and next to him holds a bus with WIFI AP. In this case, I want to sense the WIFI AP once and again after 60 seconds to  minize these cases. I am trying to do it with a `Handler` but I dont know where exactly  the right position to place it.

**Code**

```
    public class TrackingService extends Service implements AsyncTaskCallback,
            LocationListener {
private int route_number = 0;
        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
        WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        IntentFilter wifi_IF = new IntentFilter();
       wifi_IF.addAction(android.net.wifi.WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION);
            registerReceiver(wifi_receiver, wifi_IF);
            wifi.startScan();
        }
        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            unregisterReceiver(wifi_receiver);

        private final BroadcastReceiver wifi_receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

                if (wifi.isWifiEnabled()) {

                    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                    final List<ScanResult> results = wifiManager.getScanResults();
                    if (results != null) {
                        // list of access points from the last scan
                        List<ScanResult> updatedResults = new ArrayList<ScanResult>();
                        for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
                            String ssid = results.get(i).SSID;
                            if (ssid.startsWith("KD")) {

                                updatedResults.add(results.get(i));
                            } 
                        }
                        if (updatedResults.size() > 0 && route_number == 0) {
                            String ssid = deliverBestAccessPoint(updatedResults);
                            // retrieve data from json String and parse it.
                            route_number = parse_SSID(ssid);
                        }
                    } 

                } 

            }

        };

}
```